# Create list of dates with increment of months and stop increments less than given date in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-analysis, exploratory-data-analysis

Given data

| Id | start Date | Frequency |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10-10-2015 | 1 |
| 2 | 20–10-2016 | 2 |

I required in this format

| Id | start Date | Frequency | Date1 | Dat2 | Date3 | Date4 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10-10-2015 | 1 | 10-10-2016 | 10-10-2017 | 10-10-2018 |  |
| 2 | 20–10-2016 | 2 | 20-04-2017 | 20-10-2017 | 20-04-2018 | 20-10-2018 |

If the frequency is 1 Date increments by 1 year and should not exceed 2018 year.
If the frequency is 2 Date increments by 6 month and should not exceed 2018 year.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could `apply` `pd.date_range` on each row to create your required dates and `join` back to the original DataFrame:

```
df["start Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["start Date"], format="%d-%m-%Y")
dates = df.apply(lambda x: pd.Series(pd.date_range(x["start Date"], 
                                                   "2018-12-31", 
                                                   freq=pd.DateOffset(months=12/x["Frequency"]))
                                                   ).add_prefix("Date"), axis=1)
output = df.join(dates.iloc[:,1:])

>>> output
   id start Date  Frequency      Date1      Date2      Date3      Date4
0   1 2015-10-10          1 2016-10-10 2017-10-10 2018-10-10        NaT
1   2 2016-10-20          2 2017-04-20 2017-10-20 2018-04-20 2018-10-20
```

Comment: How to start dates range from a specific year?
if the start date is in 2015 but I want the date range starting from 2017-01-01 and continuing till end date with same frequency.

Comment: `pd.date_range("2017-01-01","2018-12-31",freq="Y")`. For more, you can look up the documentation of `pd.date_range`